# Streaming large amounts of data from sql server to an Excel file via c# web service

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

So I'm trying to get the results from a stored proc (200k rows+) into an Excel file from ASP.NET but having a few difficulties.  I don't think csv is an option as the client want the numbers formatted correctly.  I've tried three third party Excel libraries but all have fallen over with so much data and are using gigabytes of memory.

I've wrote some code to generate an Excel XML file and it runs very quickly but the file is over 300megs.  If I open and save as a native Excel file it gets it down to 30megs.  At the moment my best solution is to zip this xml file on the server which gets it down to 7megs but the user is still going to end up with a huge file once unzipped.  Ideally I'd like to find a third party Excel library that can write a native Excel file with 200,000+ rows without killing the server, any ideas?

Comment: What version of Excel are you writing to? `xls` or `xlsx`?

Comment: Have you tried the native COM API for Excel? [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)

Comment: File format doesn't matter as long as it opens in Excel 2007 so xls or xlsx.  Haven't tried the COM API as I believe that requires Excel installed on the server? (not an option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up generating a xlsx myself, it turns out the format is pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really quick POC I made that writes 3 columns of 255 characters 200,000 times (600,000 cells). The final file comes in at 4.85MB on my machine.

```
        string ExportFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.xlsx");
        string DSN = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";", ExportFile);

        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection Con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(DSN))
        {
            Con.Open();
            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand Com = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand())
            {
                Com.Connection = Con;
                Com.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [TestSheet] (A1 varChar(255), B1 varChar(255), C1 varChar(255))";
                Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string A1 = new string('A', 255);
                string B1 = new string('B', 255);
                string C1 = new string('C', 255);
                Com.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO [TestSheet] (A1, B1, C1) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", A1, B1, C1);
                for (var i = 1; i <= 200000; i++)
                {
                    Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            Con.Close();
        }
```

On a server I'm not all sure what's needed but you might have to install this:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks this looks like it has potential.  When I ran your code on my machine I can only generate upto 8,000 or so rows, any more gives me a blank xls.  If I descrease the lengths of the strings I can generate more, any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Can you email me the file that it generates? My email address is in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately excel is a flat file system and SQL isn't making compatibility interesting. I'm hoping Chris Haas' code will work for you. It does seem odd, 'I don't think csv is an option as the client want the numbers formatted correctly. ' if they have an SQL database they don't refer/query that instead of having an excel version of the database?

Comment: Fair question and one I've asked myself, however they're paying for this, not me :)

Comment: Typically I've witnessed this in companies I've worked in when they want to manipulate the data themselves but I'd consider that a sort of exceptional operation as opposed to a common task. Alas the business world does not always understand the 'coding' world =)